# How can I make my existing JSF2 on Tomcat 8 web application be a client to an OpenID Connect SSO server

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I have several JSF2 web applications that are running on Tomcat 8.  My company has started developing applications in .NET including an SSO server using OpenId Connect.  I was hoping that I could update my JSF applications to be clients that use the SSO server.

Is this possible?  If so, what technologies should I consider to get my JSF2 on Tomcat 8 application to be a client to an OpenID Connect Server?

I apologize for my ignorance in this area.  I have tried to search the internet and there are so many technologies and implementations that I feel too overwhelmed.  I can learn a new thing, but I don't know what I should learn.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of pac4j (http://www.pac4j.org), a security library you can use to be a client to an OpenID Connect server.

In fact, it's a security engine with multiple implementations, so you need to choose the framework you want to secure your app: simple J2E filters (https://github.com/pac4j/j2e-pac4j), Spring MVC interceptors (https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j) or Spring Security filters (https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will dive into this as soon as I can.